# Akavache security override not working

Tags: security, caching, xamarin, akavache

As you know akavache has issues with its secure storage on iOS and Android.
I am trying to override the secure storage used by Akavache.

I've been following the example given by Kent to solve this problem:
http://kent-boogaart.com/blog/password-protected-encryption-provider-for-akavache

Note: I cannot use `System.Security.Cryptography` in my code, because we are using **PCL's**. Therefore I am using `PCLCrypto`.

I use a setup class to initialize DI:

```
IPasswordProtectedEncryptionProvider providerInstance = new PasswordProtectedEncryptionProvider();
providerInstance.SetPassword("test");
Splat.Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => providerInstance, typeof(Akavache.IEncryptionProvider));
Container.RegisterSingleton<ICache>(new CacheManager());
```

I use `PasswordProtectedEncryptionProvider` as my custom override of `IEncryptionProvider`. However the methods overridden in the class, `DecryptBlock` `EncryptBlock`, do not get called!

Don't understand why its not being called.

Doesn't `() => providerInstance` override it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the timing of your registration, and the way you get your secure cache, it may be getting LIFO'd by [Akavache's default registrations](https://github.com/akavache/Akavache/blob/501b397d8c071366c3b6783aae3e98695b3d7442/src/Akavache/Registrations.cs).

To avoid the ambiguity (and for cleaner DI), I typically set up my encrypted caches as below:

```
var fsprovider = Locator.Current.GetService<IFilesystemProvider>();

var root = fsprovider.GetDefaultSecretCacheDirectory();
var dbName = "mysecrets.db";        
var path = Path.Combine(root, dbName);

var encryptionProvider = /* create + init or resolve your enc provider here */

var encryptedCache = new SQLiteEncryptedBlobCache(path, encryptionProvider);
```

To solve your specific issue, initialize the cache manager ahead of the DI:

```
CacheManager _cache = new CacheManager();

IPasswordProtectedEncryptionProvider providerInstance = new PasswordProtectedEncryptionProvider();
providerInstance.SetPassword("test");
Splat.Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => providerInstance, typeof(Akavache.IEncryptionProvider));

Container.RegisterSingleton<ICache>(_cache);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @rdavisau . You lead me to the final solution when you mentioned the LIFOs issue. I changed your answer to example how to solve the specific issue.